# How to quit a job with no notice period due to back pain?

Tags: resignation, health

I need to quit a seasonal job at a large big box hardware store  because of many reasons, one of which is back pain. This job often has me lifting heavy objects. Either through poor form or haplessness I recently hurt my back.

A personal friend of mine, also an M.D., examined me and determined some issues to confirm my suspicions. He told me more stress on my back could lead to chronic issues. This seasonal job offers no personal time off and expects weekends to be always covered, so I doubt waiting for recovery would be an option.

I know I should have other work lined up before leaving, and this job itself was just a stopgap until I decide on an official place to relocate.

**How do I immediately send a letter/email of resignation to HR or whatever would be the best method of quitting this job immediately before I aggravate my back more at work?** I do not want this biting me in the "back" (pun intended).

Comment: It heavily depends upon the local laws. In some countries, you are even eligible for paid leaves. Discuss it with HR as well as your local friends before giving them a ultimatum. Maybe they will offer you unpaid leave or leaves with some percent of salary. It won't be possible if you just give them your final decision. You even risk losing a reference and burn Bridges by resigning without talking first

Comment: @JoeStrazzere     No I do not wish to get unemployment or disability. I just want to quit without any ramifications. I am not sure how just quitting impromptu can affect me.

Comment: Voted for it - given the positive answers you received, must be the random downvoters who rarely comment, but they seem to be on every stack sadly...

Comment: Just for your health, consider the option that the problem is not the form or your work in general, but your back being too weak for that effort. Maybe try to find a good physiotherapist as these problems don't usually dissapear just by not doing a physical effort.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you injured yourself at work and the injury was caused by lack of training or insufficient safety equipment/precautions on the part of your employer, there may be need to have documentation that the injury happened on the job, and the company's insurance paying for some or all of your treatment. In this case, you need to have an *official* visit with your physician (not a friend who also happens to be an MD), with proper documentation of it being a workplace injury, and report the injury to your employer as well. As part of that visit, you should receive documentation from the physician that you aren't able to work while being treated.

IOW, if you got hurt on the job because of the job, you *shouldn't* resign immediately; you may find yourself involved (perhaps rightly so) in a worker's comp claim and need to stay with the company to complete that process. You need guidance through that process that's specific to your jurisdiction.

---

If this is *not* an injury that would fall under the above, you're over-thinking this too much IMHO. This is a seasonal retail job. It's quite likely that in 6 months, they will have completely forgotten about you.

> For health reasons, I am resigning my position effective immediately. Thank you for the opportunity to work for .

You don't owe any further explanation, you don't have to justify your decision. In the US at least, the 2 week notice period is a courtesy, not a requirement - unless it's specified in your contract.

Comment: +1 you don’t have to just quit, see a doc and look into workmans comp, paid medical leave, and so on.

Comment: If you have medical insurance, the insurer may insist on you filing for worker's compensation. Every time I check in at my HMO for any appointment that might be due to an injury they ask whether it is due to a workplace injury.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I immediately send a letter/email of resignation to HR or
>   whatever would be the best method of quitting this job immediately
>   before I aggravate my back more at work?

Use the telephone.

Talk to your manager. Explain the situation. Indicate that, due to doctor's order you will not be able to return to work and that unfortunately you physically are not able to give the normal notice period. Ask if you should follow up with some paperwork or should talk with someone else.

*This assumes that you are in the US where notice periods are the norm but are not legally required. If local laws are different, follow those.*